# document.querySelectorAll() access collection's children

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to figure out how to access the child of one of the elements in the following collection:

`var items = document.querySelectorAll(".timeline li");`

At one point I loop through the `items` and I'd like to be able access one of the child elements of the `li` that I collected. If I use `items[i]` I will get list item, but from there I'm not sure how to access the span inside of it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I use items[i] I will get list item, but from there I'm not sure
>   how to access the span inside of it.

Use `querySelector` on `items[i]`

```
var spanEl = items[i].querySelector( "span" );
```

If there are multiple `span`s, use `querySelectorAll`

```
var spanEls = items[i].querySelectorAll( "span" );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `querySelector` on `items[i]`.

```
items[i].querySelector(...)
```

**Why not just to get the `span` directly:**

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll(".timeline li > span");
```

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll(".timeline li > span");
items.forEach(function(span) {
  console.log("Parent: ", span.closest('li').getAttribute("id"));
  console.log(span.textContent);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<ul class="timeline">
  <li id="li#1">
  <span>
    span#1
  </span>
  </li>
  <li id="li#2">
  <span>
    span#2
  </span>
  </li>
  <li id="li#3">
  <span>
    span#3
  </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I need to do actions on the main li items first then on the span later on.

Comment: @PaigeMeinke using the function closest you have access to the `li`.  Well, this is an alternative to get the whole set of spans.

Comment: +1 Thanks for showing me an alternative way, but I think for my purposes, @gurvinder372 answer works best for me